# How can i display a resized image in python tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm developing a GUI in Python using Tkinter to learn image processing. GUI's process flow would be as

Load image (jpg|png|...) => Resize/ thumbnail image (240 * 240) => Preview image

```
from Tkinter import *
import PIL
class Window:       
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Image Processing test")
        master.minsize(800, 400)

        from PIL import Image
        im = Image.open("IMG_0562.png")
        size = 240, 240
        im.thumbnail(size)
        p = im.tobytes()

        # photo = PhotoImage(file="IMG_0562.gif")
        # photo = BitmapImage(data=p)
        w = Label(root, image=photo, width=240, height=240).grid(row=20, column=2)
        self.photo = photo


root = Tk()

window = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is I couldn't get the image in a proper format to use it in `Label`. As `Label` only accepts `PhotoImage` and `BitmapImage`. `PhotoImage` doesn't support `png` or `jpg` file. So I used `Image` from `PIL` to load and resize my colored image. I've tried `Image.tobitmap()` and `Image.tobytes()` too but not useful in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by saving the image in memory using `io.BytesIO()`

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import io

class Window:       
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Image Processing test")
        master.minsize(800, 400)

        im = Image.open("IMG_0562.png")
        size = 240, 240
        im.thumbnail(size)
        b = io.BytesIO()
        im.save(b, 'gif')
        p = b.getvalue()
        photo = BitmapImage(data=p)
        w = Label(root, image=photo, width=240, height=240).grid(row=20, column=2)
        self.photo = photo

root = Tk()    
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```